# Modifying csv to avoid parsing issues

Tags: r, regex

I have a csv file with rows that looks like the following:

```
2, 3, c(a, b, c), o, d
```

I want to read this csv but keep the vector c(a,b,c) in one column (variable). I was thinking to read my CSV files and change the delimeter (comma) in those vectors. For example I would change the previous vector to the following:

```
2, 3, c(a; b; c), o, d
```

That way when I read the csv file (read.csv) it will not parse the vector to separate variables. I am trying to figure out the regular expression I should use for this.

```
text <- "2, 3, c(a, b, c), o, d"
gsub("(c\\([a-z]?)(,)", "\\1;", text) #Something similar to this but as you could see I am struggling
```

The solution should work for the following cases:

```
2, 3, c(a), o, d
2, 3, c(a, b), o, d
2, 3, c(a, b, c, d), o, d
```

I am trying to do this in R so any other packages aside from using gsub will work.

Comment: If you're **really** stuck on using `,` as the delimiter for the vector, why not just drop the space and then split by `, `? For your existing set you can use this `\s*([^,]+\([^)]+\)|[^,]+)`

Comment: If you're creating this CSV consider using double-quotes, which are the "standard" way of escaping for CSV.

Comment: How did you wind up with a CSV file that looks like that in the first place? That's probably the real problem you should address.

Comment: So, no nested parentheses like in `a, b(a, b, c(a, b), d, f), c`?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Replace each c(...) with "c(...)" as suggested by @bezet in the comments and then read it in using `read.table` .  No packages are used.

```
Lines <- rep("2, 3, c(a, b, c), o, d", 3) # sample input

Lines2 <- gsub('(c\\(.*?\\))', '"\\1"', Lines)
read.table(text = Lines2, sep = ",")
```

The code gives this data frame:

```
  V1 V2          V3 V4 V5
1  2  3  c(a, b, c)  o  d
2  2  3  c(a, b, c)  o  d
3  2  3  c(a, b, c)  o  d
```

**2)** This solution is along the lines suggested in the question where we replace command with semicolons within the c(...) part. Match each shortest occurrence of (...) and within each invoke the indicated `gusb` to replace commas with semicolons.  Then replace the remaining commas with | characters and the semicolons back to commas.  Finally, read it in using `read.table` with `sep="|"`.

```
library(gsubfn)

Lines2 <- gsubfn("\\(.*?\\)", ~ gsub(",", ";", x), Lines, perl = TRUE)
Lines2 <- chartr(";,", ",|", Lines2)
read.table(text = Lines2, sep = "|")
```

**3)** or if you know the precise form match each row with the indicated pattern and `read.pattern` giving the same data frame as output.

```
library(gsubfn)

read.pattern(text = Lines, pattern = "^(\\S+), (\\S+), (\\S.+\\)), (\\S+), (\\S+)$")
```